# Medical student vs. medicine student vs. student of medicine?

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the right phrase for calling someone who is studying medicine? I've seen "medical student" a lot but I doubt about it mostly because the student him/herself is not medical! It's his/her field of study that is medical. Also I've seen that we call the school "School of medicine". What form is the true one?

Comment: *medical student, science student, law student, football player, tennis player,...* what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Student of medicine** and **School of Medicine** are the [older traditional terms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20student%20of%20medicine%2Cstudent%20of%20medicine%2Cmedical%20student&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20student%20of%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstudent%20of%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmedical%20student%3B%2Cc0), but **medical student** and **medical school** are far more common today in spoken English (at least in the US).

Adjectives are not always references to properties that inhere in the noun; they can indicate a relationship or association.